# Django 1.10, Apache 2.4 Serving Basic App on CentOS7 Getting 403 Forbidden to /

Tags: django, apache, centos

Screwing around at this point just to try and get it working.

I am getting a `403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server.` error. I have been following this guide on how to setup Apache to work with CentOS and Django:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-centos-7

Also, read several questions on SO regarding the error, but none have resolved the problem.

Fresh Django project install so should just be showing the static "it's working page" at `localhost:8000`, I would think.

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/django_test.conf**

```
Alias /static /home/dev/testserver/static
<Directory /home/dev/testserver/static>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/dev/testserver/testserver>
  <Files wsgi.py>
     Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess testserver python-path=/home/dev/testserver:/home/venvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup testserver
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/dev/testserver/testserver/wsgi.py
```

I am pretty naive when it comes to this, but do I or don't I have to run `python manage.py runserver` in addition to having `HTTPD` setup? Or does that only apply to if you are developing locally using the built in Django server?

Speaking of which, I can visit the page on the remote server using the built in Django server, but understand this highly undesirable.

I do have port `80` open and can see that it is listening for traffic.

Per the tutorial I gave the `/home/dev` directory `chmod 710` permissions and added `apache` to the same user group as the owner of the directory.

Just not seeing what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT #1**

I started just going through `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` line by line to see if anything looked add. For `group` I changed it from `apache` to `sqladmin` because I added the `apache` user to that group. Also, made sure that `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` was explicitly added. Still no luck.

At any rate I am now reading about the `pip` package for `mod_wsgi` to see if that might resolve my problems.

**EDIT #2**

The error_log says the following:

```
[Tue Jan 31 16:26:31.961512 2017] [core:error] [pid 4561] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.1.39:57651] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/dev/testserver/testserver/wsgi.py') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

[Tue Jan 31 16:26:31.986965 2017] [core:error] [pid 4561] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.1.39:57651] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/dev/testserver/testserver/wsgi.py') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://192.168.1.4/
```

Says a permission error, but as far as I know it should only be looking at `/home/dev` and `/home/venvs`. All of which have the same permissions applied as does `/home`. The user `apache` exists, and the user `apache` is part of the `sqladmin` group which is the group on all of these directories and files. I went as far as to create an `apache` group and make `sqladmin` a part of that.

List of the directory permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  3 sqladmin sqladmin   24 Jan 31 15:08 dev
drwx------. 14 sqladmin sqladmin 4096 Jan 30 21:13 sqladmin
drwxr-xr-x.  3 sqladmin sqladmin   20 Jan 31 15:05 venvs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... do I or don't I have to run python manage.py runserver in addition
>   to having HTTPD setup?

You don't never do manage.py runserver in production besides you don't need it either. That's the whole point of setting up apache

Next let's look at this:

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess testserver python-path=/home/dev/testserver:/home/venvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Though you have set the permissions for your home directory. What about the /home/venvs directory? that sounds like an entirely different user account. So have you changed the permissions and the groups accordingly for that one?

Secondly, you will need to make te /home/dev/testserver folder readable by apache as well and also executable. The execute flag on a directory is needed for a user to change into that directory. Often times you find that permissions are changed accidentally while the project is being transferred to the server.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback and clearing up the `runserver` question. I realized I didn't grant permissions for `venvs`. I granted permission `750` to both `./dev` and `./venvs`. Still running into the same issue. Also tried `770` and `777` just to see if that did anything. It didn't so changed back to `750`. Just not sure what I am missing here. Verified user is in the group. The group is `sqladmin` and it reads: `sqladmin:x:1000:sqladmin,apache`.

Comment: Also, ran `httpd -M | grep wsgi` to make sure `mod_wsgi` was running with `httpd` and it says `wsgi_module (shared)` which I guess is saying it is loaded? I haven't modified the `httpd.conf` or anything. Just installed with `yum`.

Comment: I applied them recursively so they matched the permissions on the folders that were specified in the tutorials.

Comment: please do an `ls -l` on the /home/ so that we can see the permissions too

Comment: Updated the response.

Comment: please check that all internal folders have similar permissions

Comment: I ran `chmod 750 -R` on each of those directories. Unless I am mistaken, it would apply the same permissions to everything below it, correct?

Comment: Well, i'm stumped. Did a `chown -R sqladmin:sqladmin` on each directory too. Went through and checked just about every file and folder....

Answer (score 0):

Well, whether or not it is considered a solution because I never did get Apache + mod_wsgi working, but I did get it working through [PyPi mod_wsgi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi).

Installed into the `virtualenv` and just followed the "Using mod_wsgi-express with Django" section.